# Error on Android Studio emulator: Could not connect to developer server - React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm new to react native. Recently I started to have this error on Android Studio emulator "Could not connect do developer server". Also see the [screenshot to the error on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rthu.png). The error appears each time I try to reload the page to see the changes made on Visual Code, pressing "R,R". Does anyone have already face and fix this error successfully?

Here is what I tried so far:

- Installed Metro and added the folder "assets" in in metro-config
- Verified that the emulator is connected to the wifi, airplane mode is disabled
- Added the port "localhost:8081" in the Dev setting
- Downgraded Node.js from the latest version 16.14.2, to and older one 14.17.4 and then tried 14.16.1. It still didn't work, even after I restarted the laptop
- Closed everything and run the command "react-native run-android" again, still get the error when I reload the emulator...

Any idea on the cause of this problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.